# flask redirecting with url and api key required

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I have two endpoints and I'd like to redirect from one to the other. Both require the same api key:

```
@blueprint.route("v1/method/<param>", methods=["PUT"])
@api_key_required
@write_required(api=True)
def method(param):
    return redirect(url_for('v2.method', param=param), code=307)
```

```
@blueprint.route("v2/method/<param>", methods=["PUT"])
@api_key_required
@write_required(api=True)
def method(param):
    #handle the request
```

redirection seems to work fine but it looks like api_key is not passed. I receive `unauthorised` status. What should I do?

Comment: pass the api key, maybe

Comment: Great idea, seriously. How? Cause passing `api=request.args["api_key"]` doesn't work, neither `request=request`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. `request.args` need to be pass as additional arguments. So the correct code is:

```
return redirect(url_for('v2.method', param=param, **request.args), code=307)
```